# how to control the height of a visualforce lightning action

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, action

We're checking the feasibility to roll out lightning experience to our users.

We had a couple of layouts where we had inline visualforce pages.
Since lightning experience changes the mindset of focusing more on actions rather then looking at the detailed fields of records, I would like to offer these inline pages in another way.

My first idea was to make them available to the users through a custom visualforce action.

Even though on the action, it let's you specify the height, it doesn't seem to take the height into account... and it also doesn't size the modal window opened based on the content that is in the modal. (my VF page)

Any way to fix that? Or advise to do it another way?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am fighting with the exact same problem

Comment: unfortunately not yet

Answer (score 2):

Copying [my answer](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MKfMIAW) from the Success community.

Since publisher actions use Canvas, you can resize the iframe from inside of your Visualforce page by including `publisher.js` and calling `Sfdc.canvas.publisher.resize`. You'll also need to set `html-style="height: 100%"` on your Visualforce page. You may want to utilize `{!$User.UITheme}` to only do this resizing inside of Lightning experience.

Example Code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Lead" html-style="height: 100%"/>
  <script src="/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js"/>

  <script>
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.resize( { height : "400px" } );
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now, that's currently a bug with no workaround. You can subscribe to the know issue [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eV87AAE) to track when it's solved

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible workaround if you have editing of record pages with lightning app builder enabled (Pilot in Spring 16, [GA in Summer 16](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_create_recordpage_ga_lex.htm)):

Create an (invisible) lightning component that will listen to "postMessage" events from the Visualforce page and do the resizing from the "outside". Add this lightning component to the record layout (the "outer page" containing the action button):

Component XML:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller JS:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {        
        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            if(event.data.event === 'resize') {
                console.log("!!! RESIZE received")

                var pws = document.getElementsByClassName('pageWrapper');
                var i;
                var j;
                for(i=0; i<pws.length; i++) {
                    var iframes = pws[i].getElementsByTagName('iframe');
                    console.log("pws[" + i + "] =");
                    console.log(pws[i])
                    for(j=0; j<iframes.length; j++) {
                        console.log("iframes[" + j + "] =");
                        console.log(iframes[j])
                        iframes[j].height = event.data.height;
                    }
                }
            }        
        }, false);                     
    }
})
```

Inside the (iframe'd) visualforce page, send the "resize" message to the lightning component on the out page by adding a piece of javascript as follows:

```
<script>
    window.parent.postMessage({ event: 'resize', height: 400 }, "*");  
</script>
```

Note: of course the classes used in the record layout page (pageWrapper etc.) might change, so this is tested as of Spring '16 and you might have to retest etc. with new releases and keep an eye on it (which you want to do anyway to get rid of this, once the bug linked in the other answer is fixed).